# How to import 2D position data into After Effects

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

If I have a .csv file of x / y coordinates, representing positional data of an object in an animation, what's the easiest way to apply that to a 2D null in After Effects?

Eg:

```
Frame,Xpos,Ypos
1,33,360
2,34,361
3,38,370
```

I ask because I'm trying to track movement of an object from a D3.js without having to endlessly motion-track objects.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/967614).
Copying any positional keyframes out of After Effects generates a text file like this:

```
Adobe After Effects 8.0 Keyframe Data

    Units Per Second    25
    Source Width    100
    Source Height   100
    Source Pixel Aspect Ratio   1
    Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio 1

Transform   Scale
    Frame   X percent   Y percent   Z percent   
        100 100 100 

Transform   Position
    Frame   X pixels    Y pixels    Z pixels    
    0   960 540 0   
    1   980 540 0   
    2   980 520 0   
    3   1000    520 0   
    4   1000    518 0   
    5   630 498 0   


End of Keyframe Data
```

To manipulate it, just modify the text, copy the text, and paste it back into AE.  Works like a charm

Comment: I was oing to suggest scripting, but this is much easier. A neat hack